# Get Field Number From database and insert the value to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have this structure of table name tb_fruit

```
ID    FRUIT    TOTAL
1     Apple     5
2     Orange    6
3     Grape     5
```

and I want to make an input form that have a structure like :

```
FRUIT    TOTAL    PRICE
Apple     5
Orange    6
Grape     5
```

where value of fruit and total is generated from the database and after that i want to save the post value from input from to a new database called tb_price with the structure like :

```
ID    FRUIT    TOTAL    PRICE
1     Apple     5       <$_POST['price of apple']>
2     Orange    6       <$_POST['price of orange']>
3     Grape     5       <$_POST['price of grape']>
```

i can think how to get the value from tb_fruit, but i have no idea how to insert the post data into tb_price. can someone help me?
thanks ~

Comment: There are millions of resources in the internet on how to insert data on a table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to **create** a **SQL database** using [PDO](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) and [SQL CREATE TABLE](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_create_table.asp) command. And then **fill it** using [SQL INSERT INTO](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) command.